# Get Distinct rows and their record count with where clause for the count only

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
-------------------------------------
Name of Student       |      class   
-------------------------------------
S1                            First
S11                           First
S12                           First
S13                           First
S2                            Second
S3                            Third
S31                           Third
-------------------------------------
```

Right now Im getting distinct classes with each of its count with below query

```
SELECT class,count(*) FROM students GROUP BY class
```

I get this, everything is good with this

```
array(
       "class"=> "First", "count"=>"4",
       "class"=> "Second", "count"=>"1",
       "class"=> "Third", "count"=>"2",
    )
```

but I want to apply where condition only for the counts, so I want all distinct classes, with counts as per where clause

For example if my condition is class="First"

```
SELECT class,count(*) FROM students where class="First" GROUP BY class
```

that query gives me this

```
array(
       "class"=> "First", "count"=>"4"
    )
```

but I want all distinct classes, so my expected result is the following

```
array(
       "class"=> "First", "count"=>"4",
       "class"=> "Second", "count"=>"0",
       "class"=> "Third", "count"=>"0",
    )
```

any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: I have a hard time seeing a valid use case for a query like that, one that returns demonstrably false data, but it is doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM()` to count the number of rows that match the desired condition.

```
SELECT class, SUM(class = "First") AS count
FROM students
GROUP BY class
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
SELECT class
  ,count(case when class='first' then 1 else null end) 
FROM students 
GROUP BY class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT class, IF(class='first',count(1),0)
FROM students 
GROUP BY class
```

MySQL has an `IF()` function that takes three arguments, a test, the result if true and the result if false. Since you only want to count if class is 'first' you can return 0 if the test fails and return the count (I prefer to count 1 when simply counting rows) if the test passes.

In MsSQL the same function is `IIF()`.